# Turning string into char and checking for letters

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

I'm having some issues with a piece of my code, I think it's causing an error when I try to test it with entered input that causes Visual Studios to freeze with an error message that says Unhandled exception at 0x74A1DDC2. This is the code I've written:

```
 bool isValidRomanNumber(string test) {
//Validates that a roman number was entered

char char_array[10];
strcpy(char_array, test.c_str());

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if ('I' == char_array[i] || 'V' == char_array[i] || 'X' == char_array[i]|| 'L' == char_array[i] || 'C'== char_array[i] || 'D' == char_array[i] || 'M' == char_array[i]) {
        cout << test << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I know it's this function that is causing the error because every other part of my program that I've tested is working and fine. I'm very new to C++ so I can't tell what I'm doing wrong so suggestions are extremely welcome.

Comment: strcpy is not safe: it does not check if the destination is large enough. It probably goes beyond the size of char_array. There are simpler/faster solutions - a lookup table is, probably, the fastest solution.

Comment: You cannot feed a string containing a roman number to `std::stoi`. It will throw an exception. You have to check which kind the input is the other way round. Also don't use global variables but parameters and return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of excellent solutions here.  However, I'd like to explain why your code doesn't work, because these mistakes will make your life hard, if you don't learn to avoid them.

**1) Logical error in the loop**

First, your loop will test only the first character of the string: the first execution of the `if` clause in the loop will necessarily result in a `return`, without any other chars being checked !

*Solution:* check every character and return true only after the loop has successfully checked them all.  On the contrary, if any character is invalid, return false immediately.

**2) You may process too many chars**

Second, your loop checks exactly 10 chars. If your input string is shorter,  `strcpy()` will introduce a trailing `'\0'` to mark the end of the c-string (and this character doesn't match any valid roman one), and will leave the remaining chars uninitialised (so containing garbage, most probably not a roman either).

*Solution:* make sure that the loop condition is false when the end of the c-string is reached.

**3) What happens if the input string is too long ?**

Third, `strcpy()` is not safe.  If your input string is 9 chars long, `strcpy()` will copy 10 chars into its target (because of the trailing `'\0'` terminator).   Unfortunately, if your input string is longer, `strcpy()` will continue to copy additional chars beyond the storage that was allocated for the target.  This will result in a memory corruption: it could cause nothing observable, or it could cause the programme to freeze or any other weird behaviour.

*Solution:*  use `strncpy()` to avoid the risk of buffer overflow

**Adapting your original code with no other improvement**

```
bool isValidRomanNumber(string test) {
    char char_array[10];
    strncpy(char_array, test.c_str(), 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && char_array[i]; i++) {
        if ('I' != char_array[i] && 'V' != char_array[i] && 'X' != char_array[i]&& 'L' != char_array[i] && 'C'!= char_array[i] && 'D' != char_array[i] && 'M' != char_array[i]) {
            return false;
        } 
    }  

    return true;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/cLEIoi)

**But this is legacy c++, not cool modern c++**

A far better option is to get rid of the c-strings and use only the much safer c++ `string`.  And then you don't need to worry about storage allocation either.
The good news is that it's easy:  you can just access directly the characters of your input string:

```
bool isValidRomanNumber(string test) {
    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
        if ('I' != test[i] && 'V' != test[i] && 'X' != test[i]&& 'L' != test[i] && 'C'!= test[i] && 'D' != test[i] && 'M' != test[i]) {
            return false;
        } 
    }  
    return true;
}
```

No problem if your input string would be 1000 chars long :-) It would check them all !

For even better solutions, you can now look at the other answers

Comment: Glad that it helped :-) Now, that this function checks if the string only made pf roman digits, you could start to think about an enhanced version that would also  check if the roman digits are combined according to rules (e.g. that numerals are arranged in descending order except the subtractive cases: more here https://projecteuler.net/about=roman_numerals) ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Simply check that non-valid digits cannot be found:

```
bool romanDigitsOnly(const std::string& number) {
  return number.find_first_not_of("IVXLCDM") == std::string::npos;
}
```

[find_first_not_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) returns npos if none of the specified characters found in the string.
Please note, this only checks for valid digits, not for [valid roman numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to copy the contents of the `std::string` to a `char` array.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

bool isRomanDigit(char ch)
{
    ch = std::toupper(ch);

    return ch == 'I' || ch == 'V' || ch == 'X' || ch == 'L' ||
           ch == 'C' || ch == 'D' || ch == 'M';
}

bool isValidRomanNumber(std::string const &test)
{
    for (auto ch : test)
        if (!isRomanDigit(ch))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but for it's still happening. I update my post with the whole code, would you mind taking a look to see if maybe I was wrong and I am in fact messing this up somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple alternative that checks for Roman digits using no library functions. Just a loop and a `switch` statement.

```
bool isValidRomanDigits(const std::string &str)
{
    for (char ch : str) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'I':
        case 'V':
        case 'X':
        case 'L':
        case 'C':
        case 'D':
        case 'M':
            // valid character, do nothing
            break;
        default:
            // invalid character
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm impressed that Clang can optimize this into just a handful of instructions ([live @ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/FhQALd)):

```
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
  test rcx, rcx
  je .LBB0_5
  mov rdx, qword ptr [rdi]
  mov esi, 2623043
.LBB0_2: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  movsx edi, byte ptr [rdx]
  xor eax, eax
  add edi, -67
  cmp edi, 21
  ja .LBB0_6
  bt esi, edi
  jae .LBB0_6
  add rdx, 1
  add rcx, -1
  jne .LBB0_2
.LBB0_5:
  mov al, 1
.LBB0_6:
  ret
```

Comment: with `isRomanDigit()` inlined and without `toupper()` my version is only 2 instructions longer https://godbolt.org/z/vCKztE